# BasicRNNCell biases do not get trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

My network gets stuck at training at around 70% accuracy with a validation accuracy of just more than 50% (it is a two class classification problem). I am debugging it and want to exclude the following as a reason.

The network consists, among others, of a `BasicRNNCell`:

```
rnn_cell = tensorflow.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(100)
```

tensorflow creates weights and biases for this RNN layer, which I can find using `tf.trainable_variables()`:

```
<tf.Variable 'network/rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(200, 100) dtype=float32_ref>,
<tf.Variable 'network/rnn/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(100,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

During training the values of `kernel:0` change every step as I would expect them to, the values of `bias` on the other side are all zero and do not change. I am using an AdagradOptimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

In my understanding the biases should be updated every training step like the weight is.

Is this expected behaviour? Could this be what keeps my learning getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I would not focus on a detail like that. It is hard to say from what you have given whether or not there should be a non-zero bias. When working with RNNs it is good practice to used clipped gradients. I have seen great improvements in training using this

```
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

    # Calculate and clip gradients
    params = tf.trainable_variables()
    gradients = tf.gradients(rnn.loss, params)
    clipped_gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(
        gradients, FLAGS.max_gradient_norm)
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients,params), global_step=global_step)
```

Typically a max_gradient_norm between 1 and 5 work best. I prefer the adamOptimizer as well. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the hint with clipping, didn't know about it! It seems weird to me that tensorflow creates biases by itself and puts them as tf.trainable_variables() but does not train them. Do you have an explanation for that? I have a variable sequence length static rnn defined like this: `outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=sequence_lengths)`

Comment: If they are all being initialized to zero it could be that during backpropagation the gradients are all going to zero. You could try a different activation function for your rnn cells.

Comment: They are initialized to zero and do not change during backpropagation